# Tkinter Grid Geometry Resizing issue

Tags: python-3.x, tkinter, tkinter-layout

Browse Button in Right Hand side Panel is being separated when resizing the window. I want the whole thing to stay together and resizing equally.

```
import tkinter as tk
from tkinter import ttk
from tkinter import *

class AppLayout(tk.Tk):
    def __init__(self):
        tk.Tk.__init__(self)

        
        
        self.masterPane = tk.PanedWindow(self )
        self.leftPane   = tk.Frame(self.masterPane,relief = 'raised',bg='black',width =100)
        self.masterPane.add(self.leftPane)
        
        self.rightPane   = tk.Frame(self.masterPane)
        self.masterPane.add(self.rightPane)
        
        self.masterPane.pack(fill = 'both',expand = True)
        


        name_entry    = tk.Entry(self.rightPane,font =('calibre',10,'normal'))
        Browse_Button = tk.Button(self.rightPane,text = 'Browse')
        Upload_Button = tk.Button(self.rightPane,text = 'Upload')
        
        name_entry.grid(row=1,column=1)
        Browse_Button.grid(row=1,column=2)
        Upload_Button.grid(row=1,column=1,pady =(50,0))
        

        self.rightPane.columnconfigure(1, weight=1)
        self.rightPane.rowconfigure(1, weight=1)


app = AppLayout()
app.mainloop()
```

Comment: Add `sticky="e"` (or "ew") in `name_entry.grid(...)`.  Should `Upload_Button` be put in row 2 instead?

Comment: What do you mean by "resizing equally"? For example, if I make the window wider should the entry widget become wider? Or, should it and the button remain at the same size and location, with a bunch of blank space to the right of the browser button?

Comment: From "Resizing Equally" I meant, when window is stretched , it should stay in center by maintaining the equal distance from Left and Right Border and at the same time filedialog box size should also increase. No,I am not expecting the Button size to change.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are four things you need to change:

- don't double-import tkinter. It's enough to import * from it.
- configure the second column of the rightPane to extend when you resize the window.
- Put the button at the western side (W) of the second column by adding `sticky=W` to the `.grid()` method.
- Glue the Entry widget to the Eastern and Western side of column 1. So, it will get wider when this column extends.

With the following code, it works.
You can also use the `.colmnconfigure()` and `.rowconfigure()` method on frame widgets to specify how the other pane extends and how the app resizes vertically.

```
from tkinter import ttk
from tkinter import *

class AppLayout(Tk):
    def __init__(self):
        Tk.__init__(self)

        self.masterPane = PanedWindow(self )
        self.leftPane   = Frame(self.masterPane,relief = 'raised',bg='black',width =100)
        self.masterPane.add(self.leftPane)
        
        self.rightPane   = Frame(self.masterPane)
        self.rightPane.columnconfigure(2, weight=1)
        self.masterPane.add(self.rightPane)
        
        self.masterPane.pack(fill = 'both',expand = True)
        
        name_entry    = Entry(self.rightPane,font =('calibre',10,'normal'))
        Browse_Button = Button(self.rightPane,text = 'Browse')
        Upload_Button = Button(self.rightPane,text = 'Upload')
        
        name_entry.grid(row=1,column=1,sticky=W+E)
        Browse_Button.grid(row=1,column=2, sticky=W)
        Upload_Button.grid(row=1,column=1,pady =(50,0))

        self.rightPane.columnconfigure(1, weight=1)
        self.rightPane.rowconfigure(1, weight=1)


app = AppLayout()
app.mainloop()
```

Comment: Thanks for your response and Suggestions Martin. How Can I keep the Whole thing in Center of the Widget? Currently, File Dialog Box is glued to left Border.

Comment: The quick fix would be to make column 0 extendable (`self.rightPane.columnconfigure(0, weight=1)`), so, the part left to the Entry it will extend when the window is stretched. But it might be a better idea to put the Entry widget and the buttons in a frame that can then be put in the center of column 1.

Comment: Thanks for your quick response. Appreciate your help... It worked. :)